# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MaConfigLib'.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I had tried to run one existing C# project to new system. Project is built successfully but i get an error while running the project which states:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MaConfigLib, Version=12.3.2326.2749, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=10639c8833d92508' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am not able to find Interop.MaConfigLib.dll.
I had done some digging and find some suggestion of "GAC" but it didn't help much.

Can any one tell me how to resolve this error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a reference in your project to third party library, and now you are just missing the file MaConfigLib.dll, on your old system you have installed application which library file you use in your solution, I think you should find out to whom belongs that file (i've done a little search and it shows   [MAXIMIZER SERVICES INC](https://www.maximizer.com/uk/)).
Try to find out, if it's a standalone library, then download it and register with RegAsm.exe, if not you should install the proper application and when update the reference in your project.